# Firebase Retrieve Current Child then Set as Child of another Child Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

** **EDITED** **

I need help with Firebase. What I need to do is:

1. Create a new database reference named **Tokens** (In line with Clients and Workers), and under Tokens;
2. Create another new database reference based on the child of the current user (e.g. Carpenters, Plumbers, or Electricians)

**Current code:**

```
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference tokens = db.getReference(Common.token_table);

    Token token = new Token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    //if user is already logged in, will update token
    tokens.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(token);
```

[Current database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24K7m.png)

I need this to be like this:

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hXRg.png)

[Updated Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhaom.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to get the `uid` of the authenticated user like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Having this `uid`, you can use it in every place you need across your activity. So to add the `tokenId` according to your database structure, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
rootRef.child("Tokens").child("Carpenters").child(tokenId).setValue(true);
```

And your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- Tokens
          |
          --- Carpenters
                  |
                  --- "uid1": true
```

According to your edit, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
rootRef.child("Tokens").child("Plumbers").child(uid).child("token").setValue(tokenId);
```

[image]

**Final answer:**

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference workersRef = rootRef.child("Workers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (ds.child(uid).exists()) {
                rootRef.child("Tokens").child(ds.getKey()).child(uid).child("token").setValue(tokenId);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
workersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Hi Alex! I did your codes, it created a new child under tokens with Carpenters (as .child("Carpenters")) even the user is not under Carpenters. I guess I can also summarize this question as "how to get the parent node"

Comment: Can you edit your question with how the database looks like now? And how do you want it to be? And which parent do you want to get, I don't understand.

Comment: Hi @alexmamo I updated the question. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I understood now. Please see my updated answer. Is ok now?

Comment: Hello Alex. Looks like nothing changed in the database. It didn't create the parent of the current user (e.g. Plumbers)

Comment: I don't understand you again. What is `Plumbers`? See the image in my updated answer. Isn't this what you want? If not, give me the **exact** example.

Comment: Hi Alex, please see update screenshot. The Plumbers is the parent key of the current userId ruN5PaZC0WNZYm6YJrRtbQVXOoH2 What I need is to create a child under Tokens depending on the parent key of the current userId.

Comment: I understand. Give me 10minutes.

Comment: Great! Sure! Will wait ^_^

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It works 100%. It is tested by me. Does it work also for you?

Comment: Whoaaa! Whoaaa! Whoaaa! Whoaaa! Alex!! You are such a genius!!!! It totally works!! Let me know if I can help you with anything I'll be more than happy to help! Your code works perfectly!! :)

Comment: Hi Alex! I'm wonderin' if you can help me solve this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/49306983/9419938 since I know it's a piece of cake to you :)