# Get Value of Key Based on the Parent Child of Current User Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the value in **ServiceFee**. I can't do a direct

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("RequestService").child("Plumbers").child(uid)
```

Because the child below **RequestService** *(like Plumbers)* should depend based on the Parent Child of the current user found in **Workers**

As an example shown in the screenshot, user **KO2rC..**'s parent child is **Plumbers**, so I should get that first before I can get the **ServiceFee** value

I tried the technique [in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298413/9419938) but I can't seem to recover the value, only the key and I don't need the key

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Workers");
ref.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String plumbers=datas.getKey();

    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RequestService").child(plumbers).child(uid);
    ref.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String fees=dataSnapshot.child("ServiceFee").getValue().toString();
     }
     @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

       }
    });
  }

    @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

   }
});
```

You can do the above, first add the snapshot at `child("Workers")`,then iterate and retrieve the value which is `Plumbers` using `getKey()`.

After that add a nested listener and put the retrieved `Plumbers` inside the child `child("RequestService").child(plumbers)` and retrieve the value `ServiceFee`

Comment: Hi Peter! Thank you for answering. Tried this and was able to be in the database reference that I need, tho I'm getting an error retrieving the value of ServiceFee

Error is: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: who is the current user, is it `KO2rC..`?

Comment: Yes did that and Yes it is `K02rC..`

Comment: @BlueCollar try it without userid. So inside ondatachange iterate: `for(DataSnapshot dat: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){  String fees=dat.child("ServiceFee").getValue().toString();`

Comment: I realized now why it's getting an error. `K02rc..` is the current user while `Lea2..` from _RequestService > Plumbers_ is the requesting party

Comment: yes so just iterate as in the comment and it should work, please inform me

Comment: AWESOME!!! It totally worked!! You saved me!!! Thank you so much Peter!!!!

Comment: Definitely!! Thank you <3

Comment: @BlueCollar no problem!! happy coding!!